# The "deleted:1" operator in search is not working properly

Tags: support, search, filtering

If I search for `user:7910454 is:question deleted:1` it should show me all of my questions that have been deleted. Instead, I get every question that hasn't been deleted. Same with answers. Am I not understanding the interface or is this a bug?

[image]

Try it for yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+deleted%3A1+is%3Aquestion

Comment: shouldn't be `deleted:yes` instead?

Comment: @TemaniAfif `yes` and `1` are interchangeable with all boolean-filters. I also encounter the problem using either one.

Comment: I tried your link and it worked just fine for me. I got a list of my deleted questions.

Comment: @TravisJ Maybe it is a reputation problem? You can see the quick filter in the image is on [Deleted]

Comment: I see a different screen than you for Public search. I wonder if that is an A:B test, or maybe you run an extension/userscript?

Comment: @leonheess IIRC you can only find your deleted questions from the appropriate location: `https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/<userid>`, as you don't have the reputation needed to normally see them (10k rep)

Comment: @TravisJ You are right in that the quick filters are a user script. However, the problem persists if I shut off Tampermonkey completely.

Comment: @NickA Oh, okay. I thought I can see my own deleted posts at any rep. I guess this is [status-bydesign] then (:

Comment: @leonheess not exactly. You can see them for 30days from your profile.

Comment: @Patrice 60* days

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is working properly, although in your case you do not have access to the `deleted:1` search filter as that is a 10k privilege.

[Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) > [Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) > [Access to moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)

> **Access to moderator tools**
>
> Privilege type: Moderation privilege
>   Awarded at: 10,000 reputation
>
> **Viewing deleted posts**
>
> You also have a new search operator available to find your own deleted posts: `deleted:1`.

Comment: It's strange that searching for your own deleted posts is gated behind the 10k rep threshold.

Comment: @user369450 - Stack Overflow search contains many aspects that some consider to be unnatural.